# Cant use DOM in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make dynamical table using DOM. This code is not working. I am receiving this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertRow' of null

js

```
 var persons = [
       { name:"Jurij Gagarin", birth: "9 March 1934", death:"27 March 1968" },
       { name:"Albert Einstein", birth: "14 March 1879", death:"18 April 1955 " },
       { name:"Mahatma Gandhi", birth: "2 October 1869", death:"30 January 1948" },
       { name:"Whitney Houston", birth: "9 August 1963", death:"11  February 2012" },];    
    function init() {
        table = document.getElementById('personsTab');
        tableSize = persons.length;
        //personsTab
        for(var i = 0; i < tableSize; i++){
            var row = table.insertRow(i);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            cell1.innerHTML = persons[i].name;
            cell2.innerHTML = persons[i].birth;
            cell3.innerHTML = persons[i].death;
        }
    } 
    window.onload = init();
```

html

```
    <table id="personsTab"> 
    <tr>
        <th id="name"><span>Name<span></th>
        <th id="birth"><span>Birth<span></th>
        <th id="death"><span>Death<span></th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You should probably change window.onload = init(); to window.onload = init (without the parentheses) because you do not actually want to call the function. You just want to assign the reference to the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the function before the load you have to make

```
    window.onload = function(){init();}
```

Or to be more cleaner

```
    window.onload = init;
```

The problem was you calling the function and not passing it

Answer (score 2):

You should probably change `window.onload = init();` 
to `window.onload = init` (without the parentheses) because you do not actually want to call the function. You just want to assign the reference to the function to the window.onload event

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having a scope problem.  Because you did not declare table as a var, it is not visible inside the for loop.

Try

```
var table = document.getElementById('personsTab');
```

Comment: Thx for reply. It is not a problem. I have tried it.